# how to calculate maximum allowable current density for a PCB trace?

Tags: pcb

How to calculate maximum current density(J) for a copper pcb trace.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246172/how-to-choose-trace-width-for-very-high-current-pcb).

Comment: There are tables and online calculators such as https://www.eeweb.com/tools/external-pcb-trace-max-current  Also there are tools such as saturn https://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit/

Comment: Depends on how the heat is removed. Air flow good. Underlying planes ---- less good. Only flowing along the trace, and trace is long.....very not good.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments above, a general and easily-remembered rule of thumb for max current in wires is to not allow more than 500A per cm^2 (cross-sectional area). So, for example, if you want a quick calculation for a trace to carry 1A, then the trace will need a minimum cross-sectional area of 1 A / 500 (A per cm^2) = 0.002 cm^2. Very long traces will have greater losses due to resistance, so should be beefed up beyond that.